# Flutter custom font only rendering two weights despite font metadata having the exact weight numbers

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, flutter-dependencies

My import in `pubspec.yaml` is standard enough. I do know that pubspec ignores the weight.

```
fonts:
  - family: Museo_Slab
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_100.otf
        weight: 100

      - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_300.otf
        weight: 300

      - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_500.otf
        weight: 500

      - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_700.otf
        weight: 700

      - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_900.otf
        weight: 900
```

The font metadata in FontBook shows the exact number of 100, 300, etc. When rendering:

```
Text(
  'Museo Slab 700',
  maxLines: 2,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Museo_Slab',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      fontSize: 20,
      color: Colors.black),
),
```

Flutter picked only the first two weights and renders like this.

[Not great screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQwZM.png)

When it should be like this

[Sanity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwjDk.png)

I have checked the font metadata and tried uninstalling and reinstalling the fonts, but I still am not seeing the correct weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same problem. The only fix i could find is to define the family individually:

```
- family: Museo_Slab100
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_100.otf

- family: Museo_Slab300
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_300.otf

- family: Museo_Slab500
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_500.otf

- family: Museo_Slab700
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_700.otf

- family: Museo_Slab900
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Museo_Slab/Museo_Slab_900.otf

                        const Text(
                          'Museo Slab 100',
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Museo_Slab100',
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Museo Slab 300',
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Museo_Slab300',
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Museo Slab 500',
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Museo_Slab500',
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Museo Slab 700',
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Museo_Slab700',
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Museo Slab 900',
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Museo_Slab900',
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
```

Comment: If this is the only way to make it work, shame on Flutter for making something basic so idiotic! Thank you so much for the answer!